# Else function is not functioning

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to get this code running for quite a while, but with no luck.

```
function clicck() {
if(f == 129) {
    document.getElementById("displayy").style.display = "none";
    return f;
} else {
    document.getElementById("displayy").style.display = "inline";
}
}
var lkj = document.getElementById("displayy");
var f = lkj.offsetHeight;
```

This code sets the display: none for "displayy" elements and the value of f is set to 0, when the first time the function is activated. However, if the function is activated once the f variable is equal to 0, the else function doesn't set the display: inline. What is the reason behind this error?

Comment: please give more background to what you are trying to do here, giving the variables meaningful names can help also.

Comment: Please consider that this statement `var f = lkj.offsetHeight;` does not mean that `f` will *always* have the same value as the offset height of the element. In the code you pasted, f only has *the initial value* and never changes. Please paste the code which changes `f` if you have any,

Comment: I have no idea how to get the code the right way, so i'll just paste it as it is.       <button onclick="clicck()">Select</button>
  <div id="displayy">
  <li><a onclick="click()">Flowers by ocassion</a></li>
  <li>Birthday</li>
  <li >Aniversery</li>
  <li >Funeral</li>
  <li >Wedding</li>
  <li >Valentine</li></div>    . This is my first js script, so i have little to no idea what I'm doing. The var f  changes whenever the function is activated, it changes to 0, because if(f == 129) {style.display = "none"}. At least that's what I think happens. @ppeterka

Comment: Ok, there is a confusion then: *`f` will **not** follow the changes of `lkj.offsetHeight` without **explicitly** assigning it a new value.* Whenever you assign it a new value, it gets that in that moment in time.  If the right hand side is a variable, and it changes, `f` will still retain its original value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that helped me a lot. @ppeterka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to retrieve the value of `f` is outside the function, so it only gets set once. Try this instead:

```
function clicck() {
    var lkj = document.getElementById("displayy");
    var f = lkj.offsetHeight;
    if(f == 129) {
        lkj.style.display = "none";
        return f;
    } else {
        lkj.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `f` is set when the script initially runs. You haven't written any code that will ever change it. So it will **always** be 129 (or always be something other that 129).

You need to remeasure it inside the function.